# Misaligned coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am new to QGIS, and have just uploaded my first raster layer, plotting ecological data in Africa.

However, I noticed that points above and below the equator appear shifted (see image). My CRS is EPSG:4326, but I unfortunately cannot find any metadata to confirm that this is correct... If anyone has some troubleshooting tips, or know what may be going on.

Source of the data: https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/HJYYTI&version=2.0 . (Note: I had to manually edit a line break on line 4166 to load in the data)

[image: QGIS output]

Comment: I get `2024-03-06T16:20:27     WARNING    afr_aez09 : /home/iturton/Downloads/afr_aez09.asc, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 4169: /home/iturton/Downloads/afr_aez09.asc, band 1: File short, can't read line 4166.` when I try to load that ASC file and the file does appear to be corrupt there. I think you need to talk to the supplier

Comment: @IanTurton thank you very much for downloading the data. I also got that issue and manually removed a line break on line 4166 (I added that to the question). I thought that I may have misconfigured my environment, but I'm realizing that the problem might be at the source of the data

Comment: It wasn't just a line break there were a bunch of binary in there too, which is why your later rows are offset